# Как перегрузить оператор для класса с произвольным типом

Tags: c#, .net, дерево

как я могу перегрузить оператор "+", чтобы можно было получить сумму двух узлов двоичного дерева поиска, учитывая то, что тип я у них сделал произвольным, но если будет тип Int у узлов, то тогда можно сложить, а если другой тип, то нельзя.

Вот код:

```
class Node<T>
{
    internal T value;

    public static Node<int> operator +(Node<int> A, Node<int> B)
    {
        return new Node<int>(A.value + B.value);
    }

    public int Balance
    {
        get
        {
            if (Left == null && Right == null)
                return 0;
            else if (Left == null && Right != null)
                return 0 - Right.Height;
            else if (Left != null && Right == null)
                return Left.Height;
            return (Left.Height - Right.Height);
        }
        private set { }
    }
    public int Height
    {
        get
        {
            if (Left == null && Right != null)
                return 1 + Right.Height;
            else if (Left != null && Right == null)
                return 1 + Left.Height;
            else if (Left != null && Right != null)
            {
                if (Left.Height >= Right.Height)
                    return Left.Height + 1;
                else
                    return Right.Height + 1;
            }
            else
                return 0;
        }

        private set
        {
        }

    }
```

Я хочу

1. сделать так, чтобы эти оператором можно было воспользоваться только если тип значения узла Int
2. не использовать для этого отдельный новый класс `IntNode : Node<int>` , а сделать это прямо в `Node<T>`

Мне выводит такую ошибку:

> Тип одного из параметров бинарного оператора должен быть вмещающим.

Comment: Частично это можно сделать на основе IConvertible, но с runtime проверкой и кучей кода https://stackoverflow.com/a/756995/698589 Не думаю это будет сколько нибудь эффективно.

Comment: Вам нужно что бы проверка на int была во время компиляции?

Comment: Много предложений [такого рода](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/164) поэтому возможно в следующих версиях языка будет реализовано

Comment: Сложение, операция специфичная для T, а не для Node, нет смысла её туда пытаться пихать, реализуйте её как extention для Node<int>

Comment: Вообще, вы пытаетесь сделать довольно странную вещь, у вас есть дерево<T>, и дерево<T>, вы делаете операцию их сложения, в результате которого структура обоих деревьев теряется, и получается новое дерево с одним узлом с содержимом T+T от корневых узлов дерева, выглядит сомнитель

Comment: у меня есть дерево<T>, в котором есть узлы<T>, для которых я хотел написать перегрузку оператора +, чтоб можно было складывать значения узлов. Ну применение может быть любым: Создать новый узел, значение которого равняется Узел1+Узел2, 
структура не теряется, Left Right у этого узла в любом случае будет Null.У меня на лабораторной по связному списку было задание"найти средний арифметический элемент, удалить его и вернуть".Для такого же задания но для дерева вот эта перегрузка оператора была бы неплохой.Но на самом деле с точки зрения ООП лучше создать новый класс для Int и там уже это делать.

Comment: простите за иногда встречающиеся пропуски запятых, а также стилистические ошибки, просто не хватало места :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> сделать так, чтобы эти оператором можно было воспользоваться только если тип значения узла Int

Невозможно. Это невозможно даже в C++ с его текстовыми шаблонами формата "найти-заменить" (оператор будет доступен, но при компиляции вывалится 10КБ текста ошибок в потрохах инклюдов).

Если класс имеет разные члены в зависимости от параметров, то это не один класс. Вряд ли от этого принципа отступятся.

> не использовать для этого отдельный новый класс `IntNode : Node<int>`, а сделать это прямо в `Node<T>`

Много вариантов:

1. Построить `Expression` с оператором, скомпилировать.
2. Сгенерировать IL в рантайме.
3. Воспользоваться отражениями.
4. Воспользоваться dynamic, который воспользуется отражениями.

Чистого варианта нет. Возможно, когда-нибудь будет, но я бы не сильно надеялся, что это случится скоро: у задачи [Exploration: Shapes and Extensions](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/164) нет ни статуса, ни майлстона (даже "X.0").